# Divide class students into breakout rooms

Tags: node.js, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, backtracking

In a school, I have multiple classes. Each class could be divided into breakout rooms of 3 or 4 students randomly. We want to avoid duplicate breakout rooms at least we want more randomness and connect new students not completely similar to the last 2-3 breakouts. If all combinations of breakout rooms are exhausted, divide them randomly into a given group size. Do you have better way to do this or optimize this algo ?

```
function calculateDissimilarity(group1, group2) {
        let commonStudents = 0;
        for (const student of group1) {
            if (group2.includes(student)) {
                commonStudents++;
            }
        }
        return commonStudents;
    }
    
    function generateBreakoutRooms(students, groupSize, previousGroups) {
        // Shuffle students array to add randomness
        shuffle(students);
    
        let breakoutRooms = [];
        let remainingStudents = [...students];
    
        // Continue until all students are assigned
        while (remainingStudents.length > 0) {
            let room = [];
    
            // Fill the room with either 3 or 4 students
            for (let i = 0; i < groupSize && remainingStudents.length > 0; i++) {
                room.push(remainingStudents.pop());
            }
    
            // Prioritize dissimilarity with previous groups
            if (previousGroups.length > 0) {
                let maxDissimilarity = -1;
                let mostDissimilarGroup = null;
    
                for (const previousGroup of previousGroups) {
                    const dissimilarity = calculateDissimilarity(room, previousGroup);
                    if (dissimilarity > maxDissimilarity) {
                        maxDissimilarity = dissimilarity;
                        mostDissimilarGroup = previousGroup;
                    }
                }
    
                // If room is too similar to a previous group, shuffle and try again
                if (maxDissimilarity <= 1) {
                    remainingStudents.push(...room);
                    shuffle(remainingStudents);
                    continue;
                }
            }
    
            breakoutRooms.push(room);
        }
    
        return breakoutRooms;
    }
    
    function shuffle(array) {
        // Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        }
    }
    
    // Example usage
    const students = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve", "Frank", "Grace", "Hannah"];
    const previousGroups = [["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"], ["David", "Eve", "Frank"]];
    const groupSize = 3; // Or 4
    const breakoutRooms = generateBreakoutRooms(students, groupSize, previousGroups);
    console.log(breakoutRooms);
```

Comment: How many students do you typically have in a class? How many times during a semester will you do the breakouts?

Comment: @JimMischel class students max can be upto 500 and they will do match once every 2 week.